# What is the equivalent of the LEFT plus FIND function in R?

Tags: regex, r, excel

I am trying to extract the first few characters from a column in a data frame. What I need is first few character till a "," is encountered.

Data:

```
texts
12/5/15, 11:49 - thanks, take care
12/5/15, 11:51 - cool
```

What I need is

```
texts                                   date
12/5/15, 11:49 - thanks, take care     12/5/15
12/10/15, 11:51 - cool                 12/10/15
```

I tired using this, but this returned everything without the columns

```
df$date <- sub(", ", "", df$date, fixed = TRUE)

 and 

df$date <- gsub( ".,","", df$texts)
```

Excel equivalent

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND(",",A1,1)-1)
```

Comment: `df$date <- sub('(^.*?),.*', '\\1', df$texts)`

Comment: worked thanks a lot!!1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sub`:

```
sub('(^.*?),.*', '\\1', df$texts)
# [1] "12/5/15" "12/5/15"
```

The pattern matches

- the start of the line `^` followed by any character `.` repeated zero to infinity times, but as few as possible `*?`, all captured `( ... )`
- followed by a comma `,`
- followed by any character, repeated zero to infinity times `.*`

which will match the whole line, and replaces it with

- the captured group `\\1`.

---

Other options: `substr`, `strsplit`, `stringr::str_extract`.

If you're planning on using said dates, `as.Date` (or `strptime`, if you want the times too) can actually strip out what it needs:

```
as.Date(df$texts, '%m/%d/%y')`  # or '%d/%m/%y', if that's the format
# [1] "2015-12-05" "2015-12-05"
```

---

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(texts = structure(1:2, .Label = c("12/5/15, 11:49 - thanks, take care", 
                "12/5/15, 11:51 - cool"), class = "factor")), .Names = "texts", 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation too!! Deserved an up vote

Answer (score 2):

Why not just,

```
sub(',.*', '', df$texts)
#[1] "12/5/15" "12/5/15"
```

Comment: THat is a simple option.  Plus one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
l <- strsplit (df$date, split = ",")
```

to split the text using the coma and then

```
sapply (l, "[", 1)
```

to keep just the first part.